# CodeIgniter: Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings (remote database server)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Everything was working fine until yesterday and suddenly this message started popping up.
`Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.`
The database setup is a secondary one using a remote server and loaded as `$db = &get_instance()->load->database('db2', true);`

With a custom mysqli connection script it works.

What could possibly go wrong suddenly?

Comment: was there any update of php or mysql at the server?

Comment: Check your base_url and database configuration in application/config/config.php and application/config/database.php files

Comment: There was no update, the PHP is 5.4.37, had to compile that version to test the program on my machine, it works fine on local. config.php and database.php seems totally fine.